# How to check user is using my application facebook

Tags: facebook, authentication

I want check how to know user is using my application facebook

Example: One user go to application page, i set user online, when user close application page, i set user offline

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't heard from a user for some time, chances are that he closed a page with your app.

Memorize last time a user did anything in your app, and set a timeout. If N minutes later there are no new actions, you mark him offline.